# Why is my 2nd thumbnail coming under the first one? I used inline block but it's still coming down

Tags: css

I am very new to coding and was trying to build this YouTube clone I saw on the internet but I'm stuck. I can't understand what's happening.

I literally did the same thing as the author of the video. But somehow my block of the second video keeps coming under the first one instead of coming at the right of it.

```css
p{
  font-family:roboto,ariel;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
.searchbar{
  display:block;
}

.video-preview{
  width:300px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right:15px;
}

.thumbnail {
width:300px;
}

.video-title{
  margin-top:0;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:500;
  line-height:20px;
  margin-bottom:12px;

}


.channel-picture{

  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:50px;
}

.video-info{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
}

.profile-picture{
width:40px;
border-radius: 50%;

}

.thumbnail-row{
  margin-bottom:12px;
}

.video-author,.video-stats{
  font-size:12px;
  color:rgb(96,96,96);
}

.video-author{
  margin-bottom:4px;
}
```

```html
      <input class="searchbar" type="textbox" placeholder="search">
            
<div class="video-preview">
  <div class="thumbnail-row"> 
<img class="thumbnail" src="thumbnails/thumbnail-1.webp">
  </div>
  <div class="channel-picture">
    <img class="profile-picture"src="channel-pictures/channel-1.jpeg"> </div>
<div class="video-info">
 <p class="video-title">
    Talking Tech and AI with Google CEO Sundar Pichai!
 </p>
<p class="video-author">
Marques Brownlee
</p>
<p class="video-stats">
3.4M views · 6 months ago
</p>
</div>

<div class="video-preview">

  <img class="thumbnail" src="thumbnails/thumbnail-2.webp">


<p class="video-title">
    
Try Not To Laugh Challenge #9
</p>
<p class="video-author">
Markiplier
</p>

<p class="video-stats">
  19M views · 4 years ago
</p>

</div>
```

i was expecting it to come at the side . can someone explain to me what i did wrong? and why is my block coming down instead of coming at the right side of the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your principal issue is that you didn't close the first `video-preview` div, so the other one was its child. About my portion of code added (a container) you can research more about Flex containers with this [funny game](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) or reading the proper [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

I attached a working snippet as example.

Note: I replace the images so we can run in my snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>

<head>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>youtube.com clone</title>
  <style>
    p {
      font-family: roboto, ariel;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .searchbar {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .video-preview {
      width: 300px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin-right: 15px;
    }
    
    .thumbnail {
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    .video-title {
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    .channel-picture {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    .video-info {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    .profile-picture {
      width: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .thumbnail-row {
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    .video-author,
    .video-stats {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
    }
    
    .video-author {
      margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
    
    /* New code*/
    .video-container {
      display: flex;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <input class="searchbar" type="textbox" placeholder="search">
  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-preview">
      <div class="thumbnail-row">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=1">
      </div>
      <div class="channel-picture">
        <img class="profile-picture" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=1"> </div>
      <div class="video-info">
        <p class="video-title">
          Talking Tech and AI with Google CEO Sundar Pichai!
        </p>
        <p class="video-author">
          Marques Brownlee
        </p>
        <p class="video-stats">
          3.4M views · 6 months ago
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-preview">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=1">
      <p class="video-title">
        Try Not To Laugh Challenge #9
      </p>
      <p class="video-author">
        Markiplier
      </p>
      <p class="video-stats">
        19M views · 4 years ago
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>

</HTML>
```